Can the following Pytorch operations be backwarded?
I have a tensor A, which is from original point cloud data. Its size is (N,3). Besides, I have a tensor B.It is an output score tensor by a neural network.Its size is (N,1). I firstly use torch.cat to cat A and B on the 1 dim. Then I use torch.argsort to order the catted tensor according to the value of the last column and get the indices. Then I used torch.gather to sort the catted vector. After the catted vector is sorted, I will use the first 10 rows of the catted tensor to calculate loss. When I calculate loss, I will use the first three columns in the first 10 rows, which is from the original point cloud data.
Can the process be backwarded(the gradients are not 0.) by Pytorch？If the answer is no, please tell me how to slove the problem? Thanks.


After the catted vector is sorted, I will use the first 10 rows of the catted tensor to calculate loss.

You need to use the neural network's output to calculate loss, not the indices it produces with argsort. The operation that extracts indices from the scores will lose the gradients because such operation is not differentiable.
import torch
out = torch.randn(10, 100).requires_grad_(True)
t_v, t_i = torch.topk(out, 10, dim=-1)
print(t_v.requires_grad) # prints True
print(t_i.requires_grad) # prints False

Simply, you have to figure out a way to compute the loss from t_v to be able to propagate.
This post on soft topk may be of interest to you.

Thank you for your reply. However, when I use your code, I found that the function torch.topk cannot implement my needs. I want to rank a tensor only according to the value of the last column. However, it ranked column by column.

scores, indices = torch.sort(scores_final[:, 0], descending=True)
keypoints_scores=scores[:self.num_keypoints].unsqueeze(1)
# post processing
object_points=object_points.permute(0,2,1).squeeze(0)
sorted_points = object_points[indices]
keypoints= sorted_points[:self.num_keypoints, :3]

How to make the codes above differentiable and not change the functionality？

there is no easy way to make the above code differentiable. You have a peculiar use-case of using NN scores to select some data which in-turn is used for loss computation. If you extract indices and throwaway the NN scores, you will break the auto grad graph.

your question makes me remember the problem of association in multi-object tracking. There, they got away with directly regressing the points and using some matching algo like Hungarian algorithm to select the tracklets (in your case you can select the point cloud data, but you will have to regress the Nx3 values from your NN).

Thank you very much! I will try in another way.
